# Правильность вычисления по формуле наивного байесовского классификатора

Tags: математика, статистика, теорема-байеса, наивный-байесовский-классификатор, статистический-анализ

```
P(category∣token) = P(token∣category) * P(category) / P(token)
```

- P(category∣token) — вероятность что токен принадлежит класса category, именно её нам надо рассчитать;
- P(token∣category) — вероятность встретить токен среди всех токенов класса category;
- P(category) - безусловная вероятность встретить токен класса c в корпусе токенов;
- P(token) - безусловная вероятность встретить токен в корпусе токенов;

```
P(token∣category) = token(category) / category
```

- token(category) - количество вхождений токена во всех документах класса category
- category - общее количество токенов в документах класса category

```
P(category) = token(category) / T
```

- token(category) - количество токенов в классе category;
- Т - общее количество токенов в обучающем множестве;

```
P(token) = token/T
```

- token - количество вхождений токена;

---

- T (общее количество токенов): 4502
- token (количество вхождений токена): 1
- category (общее количество токенов в документах класса category): 1622
- token(category) (количество токенов в классе category): 1

```
P(token) = 1 / 4502
P(token) = 0,000222123500666
```

```
P(category) = 1622 / 4502
P(category) = 0,360284318081
```

```
P(token∣category) = 1 / 1622
P(token∣category) = 0,000616522811344
```

```
P(category∣token) = 0,000616522811344 * 0,360284318081 / 0,000222123500666
P(category∣token) = 1
```

Для одного токена формула на мой взгялд хорошо отработала. Но для нескольких токенов не совсем понятен алгоритм

```
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = P(category) * P(token1,...,tokenN∣category) / P(token1,...,tokenN)
```

P(category) - всегда будет неизменным

Допустим есть два разных токена с теми же числами

```
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = (1622 / 4502) * (1 / 1622) * (1 / 1622) / ((1 / 4502) * (1 / 4502))
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = 0,360284318081 * 0,000616522811344 * 0,000616522811344 / (0,000222123500666 * 0,000222123500666)
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = 0,360284318081 * 0,000616522811344 * 0,000616522811344 / (0,000222123500666 * 0,000222123500666)
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = 0,360284318081 * 3,80100376907e-07 / 4,93388495481e-08
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = 0,360284318081 * 7,70387595958
P(category∣token1,...,tokenN) = 2,77558569668
```

Из-за отношений произведения P(token1,...,tokenN∣category) и произведения P(token1,...,tokenN) число в ряде случаев будет неуклонно расти, что даст вероятность более нуля. Как в таком случае интерпретировать значение классификатора?

Ссылки

- Наивный байесовский классификатор https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: Вы неправильно оценили знаменатель Z. В русской википедии нет формулы для него. Есть в английской: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

Comment: Попробовал заменить знаменатель (если правильно интерпретировал формулу) на
```
sum(P(token1,...,tokenN∣category)*P(category))
```
но всё равно результат намного выше нуля

Comment: "что даст вероятность более нуля" - почему это проблема? Судя по цифрам, вы имели в виду "вероятность более единицы"? )

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, больше единицы. Хотел ориентироваться на то, что вероятность принадлежности к категории в сумме с вероятностью не принадлежности к категории будет составлять единицу. Ориентировочно показатель вероятности принадлежности документа к категории более 0.5 или менее

Answer (score 0):

Пусть у нас есть:

T = 4502 - число токенов

||D|| - общие число документов, в множестве документов для обучения классификатора.

||C|| - число документов в категории C

||!C|| - число документов в категории "не C", `||D|| == ||C| + ||!C||` (все документы принадлежат какой-то категории.)

a, b - найденные в тестируемом документе токены.
Пусть, для каждого токена, в наборе обучения есть по одному документу, и они принадлежат категории C.

```
p(C|a,b) = ?

p(C) = ||C|| / ||D||
p(a|C) = 1 / ||C||
p(b|C) = 1 / ||C||

p(!C) = ||!C|| / ||D||
p(a|!C) = 0 / ||!C||
p(b|!C) = 0 / ||!C||

Z = p(C)*p(a|C)*p(b|C) + p(!C)*p(a|!C)*p(b|!C) 
  = ||C|| / ||D|| / ||C|| / ||C||
  = 1 / ||D|| /  ||C||

p(C|a,b)  = p(C)*p(a|C)*p(b|C) / Z 
          = ||C|| / ||D|| / ||C|| / ||C||  / ( 1 / ||D|| /  ||C|| )
          = 1.
```

Собственно если токены появляются только в множестве C  - будет получаться строго единица.
Если есть два токена: один принадлежит только документам С, другой только "не C" - будет деление 0./0. ...

Comment: p(a|!C) = 0 / ||!C|| там точно нуль?

Comment: @RemiZOffAlex  Это количество документов, содержащих `a` в `!C`. (По вашему условию, у нас оди  документ в `C`.)